# Sequelize "having" clause with min / max aggregation

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a query using Sequelize v4.3 that will return rows where the min date in a joined table is greater than now. The database is postgres 9.6.

There is an "order" table with columns "id", "name", etc., and a "guarantee" table with columns "id", "order_id", "start_date", "end_date", etc.

Here is an example of a SQL query which produces the result I am hoping for:

```
SELECT
  "order"."id",
  "order"."name",
  min("guarantees"."start_date") AS "start_date",
  max("guarantees"."end_date")   AS "end_date"
FROM "api"."order" AS "order"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "api"."guarantee" AS "guarantees" ON "order"."id" = "guarantees"."order_id"
WHERE "order"."is_enabled" = TRUE
GROUP BY "order"."id"
HAVING min("guarantees"."start_date") >= now();
```

Here is the Sequelize query that gets me 90% of the way there, minus the "having" clause:

```
Order.findAll({
  attributes: [
    'id',
    'name',
    [sequelize.fn('min', sequelize.col('guarantees.start_date')), 'start_date'],
    [sequelize.fn('max', sequelize.col('guarantees.end_date')), 'end_date'],
  ],
  group: ['order.id'],
  include: [
    { model: Guarantee, attributes: [] },
  ],
})
```

I have everything but the "having" clause working. Here are some things I have tried:

```
having: { '$min("guarantees"."start_date")$': { $gte: sequelize.fn('now') } }

having: { [sequelize.fn('min', sequelize.col('guarantees.start_date'))]: { $gte: sequelize.fn('now') } }

having: ['$min("guarantees"."start_date") >= now()']

// This is the way described by sequelize author: see https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/1585#issuecomment-39317886
having: ['min(?) >= ?', '"guarantees"."start_date"', sequelize.fn('now')],
```

Most of these result in the error: "Support for literal replacements in the `where` object has been removed."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished using a Sequelize where function in the having clause:

```html
complete: {
  having: sequelize.where(this.sequelize.fn('max', sequelize.col('guarantees.end_date')), {
    $lte: sequelize.fn('now'),
  }),
}
```

Comment: Did you mean 'min', not 'max'?

Comment: What is complete here ? Care to explain, where do I put this?